# Convert image points of interest to coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have some images with a given height and width and a list of POIs as a list of integer values.
I want to convert this POIs to list of (x, y) coordinates. I'm aware this can be done by a builtin `for` loop. I'm looking for a more efficient way using np, Pillow, opencv2 or friends.

Here is an example:

```
Image WxH: 1024x1024
POIs: [10, 1025, ...]

Result: [(10, 0), (1, 1), ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished succinctly with a list comprehension:

```
WIDTH = 1024
pois = [10, 1025, ...]

coordinates = [(p % WIDTH, p // WIDTH) for p in pois]
```

Alternatively, you may use the [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) builtin to perform the division and remainder computations simultaneously. This will, however, produce pairs in the revere order from what you expect, so you will need to add an additional call to `reverse`:

```
coordinates = [reverse(divmod(p, WIDTH)) for p in pois]
```

While perhaps being more efficient, this may the composition of the resulting list less clear.

Comment: This is the more readable solution. Some background and examples are here: https://www.kaggle.com/julian3833/2-understanding-and-plotting-rle-bounding-boxes

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific function for this:

```
np.unravel_index(pois, (ysize, xsize), order='C')
>>> (array([0, 1]), array([10,  1]))
```

which are the expected y,x coordinates (first array for y, second array for x).

There is also the opposite function, `np.ravel_multi_index()`.